# When I launch a gui app via ssh on Windows 7, why is the GUI not rendered?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty

Machine A is running Putty connected to Machine B:

C:\Putty>runas /user:admin "notepad"

Machine B is running freesshd server:

Starts the notepad.exe process, but does not render the GUI.

Am I launching the GUI application incorrectly or is there a command/method to access the GUI of the application when it is launched from a remote ssh connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found an answer using the psexec tool:

psexec \remotePC -u user -p pass -d -i "myapp.exe" someArgs

This will launch an interactive GUI application on my remote machine.

Comment: I'm glad you got something working, but technically you aren't answering the question you asked. You asked *why* you don't see the GUI on your screen when you run a command on the remote machine with SSH. [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is not SSH.

Comment: Oh, my bad, my intention was to launch the application GUI on machine B (the one running the ssh server) not the one where I issue the command from. I was already aware that ssh would not transmit the GUI (unless there is something like X11 forwarding for Windows).

Answer (score 1):

SSH is letting you send commands through to your computer's shell. However, it does not provide a mechanism for the remote machine to send the images to your local machine.

If you want to use GUI applications on the remote machine, you should look into something like tunneling VNC over SSH, or using a different method entirely (such as RDP) to connect to your remote machine.

Comment: I was hoping that the application would render its GUI on the local machine B, not the remote machine.

Comment: @os2firefox It doesn't have a way of doing that though. Notepad doesn't know anything about the fact that you are connecting from a remote machine.